# I am trying to install onnx from local source using windows 10 , visual studio 2019 and anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, msbuild, anaconda, msbuild-task

-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.18363.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (project):
Failed to run MSBuild command:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe
```

to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.0+b89cb5fde for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 11/5/2020 5:01:59 PM.
Project "C:\Users\ahmed\onnx\.setuptools-cmake-build\CMakeFiles\3.19.0-rc1\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.Cpp.ToolsetLocation.props(50,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160Platforms\x64\Platform.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160Platforms\x64\Platform.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk. [C:\Users\ahmed\onnx\.setuptools-cmake-build\CMakeFiles\3.19.0-rc1\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\ahmed\onnx\.setuptools-cmake-build\CMakeFiles\3.19.0-rc1\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\ahmed\onnx\.setuptools-cmake-build\CMakeFiles\3.19.0-rc1\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.Cpp.ToolsetLocation.props(50,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160Platforms\x64\Platform.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160Platforms\x64\Platform.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk. [C:\Users\ahmed\onnx\.setuptools-cmake-build\CMakeFiles\3.19.0-rc1\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.04
```

Exit code: 1

Answer (score 0):

The error is that the import node in your `VCTargetsPath.vcxproj` file has some illegal characters, so the path cannot be recognized by the system and the file cannot be found.

The issue is this path in your  `VCTargetsPath.vcxproj` file:

```
<Import Projects="xxxx\xxx\x64\Platform.props" />
```

**So** you should check this path or you can share this info with us for better support.

**I found** that there is some some garbled code on `Program Files %28x86%29` and miss a `\` on `v160Platforms`.

**The correct path** is this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Platforms\x64\Platform.props
```

=============================================================

**Suggestion**

**1) As a suggestion**, you should use this in your `VCTargetsPath.vcxproj` and for me, it works correctly.

```
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)Platforms\x64\Platform.props" />
```

**Besides**, if you use this and still get the same error, I think there is some thing wrong with your msbuild environment.

**a)** you could defines the correct property `VCTargetsPath` on the top of the `VCTargetsPath.vcxproj`

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <VCTargetsPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\</VCTargetsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

[image]

**b)** Or you could set the the correct path of `VCTargetsPath` on **System Environment Variable**.

Open **System Environment Variable** and then create a variable called `VCTargetsPath` and set it values to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\
```

[image]

**Then**, restart VS to enable it.